# how to count duplicate values of array with hashreference

Tags: perl, hash

I want to count the values of an array inside a hash and add them to the hash. My code looks like this:

```
while(my $line=<$fh>) {

                    $timestamp = $1 if $line=~ /^\s*<timestamp>(.*)</;
                    $timestamp =~ s/^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T.*\s*$/$1/;
                    $errorCode= $1 if $line=~ /^\s*<errorCode>(.*)</;

                    $hash{$timestamp}             = {} unless($hash{$timestamp});
                    $hash{$timestamp}{$errorCode} = [] unless($hash{$timestamp}{$errorCode});

                                    push @{$hash{$timestamp}{$errorCode}}, $1 if $line =~ /<errorText>(.*)</;
            }
```

Output

```
   '2019-04-05' => {    '5005' => [
                                    'Dies ist kein aktives Konto',
                                    'Dies ist kein aktives Konto'
                                  ],
                        '7112' => [
                                    'Eingabefelder nicht richtig gefuellt.',
                                    'Eingabefelder nicht richtig gefuellt.',
                                    'Eingabefelder nicht richtig gefuellt.'
                                  ],
                   }
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
'2019-04-05' => {    '5005' => { 'Dies ist kein aktives Konto' => 2 },
                     '7112' => { 'Eingabefelder nicht richtig gefuellt.' => 3 },
                }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi melpomene , yes correct. I will edit it

Comment: Tip: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Tip: Use an XML parser like XML::LibXML! It's not any more complicated, and it will save you so many headaches!

Comment: Tip: `my ($date) = $timestamp =~ /^([^T])/;` and `my ($date) = split(/T/, $timestamp);` are much cleaner ways of extracting the date.

Comment: Tip: You are using `$errorCode` even when you don't set it!!! Use `my ($error_code) = $line =~ /<errorCode>(.*)</ ? $1 : "";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
while (my $line=<$fh>) {
    $timestamp = $1 if $line=~ /^\s*<timestamp>(.*)</;
    $timestamp =~ s/^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T.*$/$1/;
    $errorCode= $1 if $line=~ /^\s*<errorCode>(.*)</;

    $hash{$timestamp}{$errorCode}{$1}++ if $line =~ /<errorText>(.*)</;
}
```

There's no need to check for the existence of intermediate structures and create them manually. Autovivification will take care of that.

Just add another layer of hash key access and increment the value. You'll end up with a count of values.